solana contract rust error anchor build
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token::{self, Mint, Token, TokenAccount, Transfer, MintTo};
declare_id!("GTPh1tdHiMWVj3yBj2S2ZZftuLPEWPyQZ6Cy7g5ibM5K");
#[program]
pub mod puj {
use super::*;
pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, name: String, symbol: String, metadata_url: String) -> Result<()> {
    let user_info = &mut ctx.accounts.user_info;
    user_info.amount = 0;

    let cpi_accounts = token::CreateToken {
        payer: ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
        mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
        rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
    };
    
    let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
    token::create_token(cpi_ctx)?;

    let cpi_accounts = token::SetMetadata {
        mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
        metadata: token::TokenMetadata {
            name,
            symbol,
            uri: metadata_url,
            seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
            creators: None,
        },
    };
    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
    token::set_metadata(cpi_ctx)?;

    Ok(())
}

pub fn deposit(ctx: Context<Deposit>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
    let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
        from: ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.accounts.to.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
    };
    let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
    token::transfer(cpi_ctx, amount)?;

    let mut user_info = ctx.accounts.user_info.load_mut()?;
    user_info.amount += amount;

    Ok(())
}

pub fn claim(ctx: Context<Claim>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
    let user_info = ctx.accounts.user_info.load()?;

    if user_info.amount < amount {
        return Err(ErrorCode::InsufficientFunds.into());
    }

    let seeds = &[ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info().key.as_ref(), &[ctx.accounts.mint.bump]];
    let signer = &[&seeds[..]];

    let cpi_accounts = MintTo {
        mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.accounts.to.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
    };
    let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(cpi_program, cpi_accounts, signer);
    token::mint_to(cpi_ctx, amount)?;

    Ok(())
}

}
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
#[account(init, payer = user, space = 8 + Mint::LEN)]
pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
#[account(mut)]
pub user: Signer<'info>,
pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
#[account(init, payer = user, space = 8 + 8)]
pub user_info: AccountLoader<'info, UserInfo>,
}
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Deposit<'info> {
#[account(mut)]
pub from: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
#[account(mut)]
pub to: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
pub user: Signer<'info>,
pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
#[account(mut)]
pub user_info: AccountLoader<'info, UserInfo>,
}
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Claim<'info> {
#[account(mut)]
pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
#[account(mut)]
pub to: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
#[account(mut)]
pub user_info: AccountLoader<'info, UserInfo>,
pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
pub mint_authority: AccountInfo<'info>,
}
#[account]
pub struct UserInfo {
pub amount: u64,
}
#[error_code]
pub enum ErrorCode {
#[msg("Insufficient funds for claim.")]
InsufficientFunds,
}
good evening, I have a rust project to create a solana contract and I have not been able to resolve this error, can someone help me please?      marcela@DESKTOP-NOEFO9H:~/video/my_tokenSolana$ anchor build
error: package solana-program v1.18.16 cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.75.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.68.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.75.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p solana-program@1.18.16 --precise ver
where ver is the latest version of solana-program supporting rustc 1.68.0-dev
I have these versions active    marcela@DESKTOP-NOEFO9H:~/video/my_tokenSolana$ cargo --version
cargo 1.79.0 (ffa9cf99a 2024-06-03)
marcela@DESKTOP-NOEFO9H:~/video/my_tokenSolana$ rustc --version
rustc 1.79.0 (129f3b996 2024-06-10)
marcela@DESKTOP-NOEFO9H:~/video/my_tokenSolana$ anchor --version
anchor-cli 0.30.0
show me this.      marcela@DESKTOP-NOEFO9H:~/video/my_tokenSolana$ rustup toolchain list
stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default) (override)
solana,
and respect to toml_edit error show me this       marcela@DESKTOP-NOEFO9H:~/video/my_tokenSolana$ cargo update -p toml_edit@0.21.0
error: package ID specification toml_edit@0.21.0 did not match any packages
Did you mean one of these?
toml_edit@0.21.1
toml_edit@0.22.14   and i sont know how to resolve

Welcom to the Solana Stackexchange! Right now your question is quite difficult to read and therefore answer. Please fix the formatting on this question using the "Edit" button.

Try using solana-program with the same version as the CLI:
solana --version

solana-cli 1.17.34 (src:b04a806c; feat:3746964731, client:SolanaLabs)

Update the Cargo.toml:
[dependencies]
solana-program = "=1.17.34"

